# Польза переписывания кода с одного ЯП на другой

Tags: любой-язык

Здравствуйте! Как я понял программист, знающий один ЯП, легко освоит любой другой. Является ли хорошей практикой переписывать код с ЯП, который знаешь на другой? Кто пробовал так учить? Как результат? Боюсь, что каша в голове будет, например, вместо `System.out.println()` будешь писать `echo`. А при переписывании потихоньку запоминаются синтаксис и, в целом, язык и API

Comment: Вот, например, перепишете вы класс с Java на C#. Да, рано или поздно вы запомните в каком языке как пишется foreach, что в C# названия методов пишутся с большой буквы, и что-нибудь ещё из различий в языках. Но каким образом, например, это поможет вам изучить то, что есть только в C#? Как в плане синтаксиса, так и стандартных классов.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Переписывание, как по мне, не лучший способ. Вы будете привязаны к парадигме и идиомам старого языка. Грубо говоря, код BASIC, переписанный на C++, останется кодом на BASIC, только другими словами. Лучше начинайте писать новые программы.

Comment: Такого вроде быть не должно, если переписывать с умом